# d3.js removing first data element of a array while adding new data element to the end of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

Im taking streaming data from sensors and  storing them in a mysql database.I want to plot  a real time graph using d3js from these streaming data.I have try to do it by loading mysql data into array  and try to remove the first element of the array inside a ajax call,all working fine till the old data loading agai n and again making a loop  between new  data.How can i fix this issue?........I am newbie to javascript and d3js need some expert help here..........

Theses are the codes

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<title>Temperature</title>


<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:white;color:#34495e">
<style>

svg {
  font: 15px sans-serif;
  fill:#0e1cf3;
}
 
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #23115a;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
 
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #94e3f7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
</style>
<script>
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 200, left: 50},
    width = 1280 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 720 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 var k = [];
// var m = [];

function fetchdata(){


 $.ajax({
  url: 'data.php',
  type: 'post',
  success: function(data){
    d3.json("data.php", function(error, data) {  
   data.forEach(function(d) {
    
        d.event = d.event;
        d.sensor1 = +d.sensor1; 
        k.push(d.event)
        
        

    });
      

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width])
    .domain(k);
     


var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, null])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.sensor1; })])
     

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .innerTickSize(-height)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(5);



var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .innerTickSize(-width)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(5);


svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")  
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.70em")
            .attr("dy", ".70em")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-65)" 
                });

 svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)

 var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.event); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.sensor1); })

    

 svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line)
   


            });
d3.selectAll("path").remove();
d3.selectAll("line").remove();
d3.selectAll("g .x.axis").remove();
d3.selectAll("g .y.axis").remove();
k.shift()



 



  },
  complete:function(data){
   setTimeout(fetchdata,700);


  }  
 });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

setTimeout(fetchdata,700);

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Being a newbie to D3 and JS, as you claimed to be, you might also want to have a look at solutions pre-built on top of D3 like [Cubism.js](https://square.github.io/cubism/) by Mike Bostock, [Epoch](http://epochjs.github.io/epoch/) and [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/). Don't get me wrong, this is just for the best quickstart experience and not meant to curb your enthusiasm; if you want to dive into it to learn the gory details you might as well do a custom built.

Comment: thnks for ur advice...